# Fusionpbx: How can I change Attended Call Transfer feature code from *4 to *2

Tags: freeswitch, fusionpbx

In fusionpbx, how can I change the feature code `*4` Attended Call Transfer to `*2`?

Answer (score 1):

it set in dialplan->local_extension and in ring_group.lua script. Just find `bind_meta_app`